# Stack overflow RSS feed failure

Tags: bug, rss

I'm using RSSOwl and the below feed fails as "Invalid or Malformed Feed".

https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=robotframework&sort=newest

When I put the feed url into 'Feed Validator' it identifies a number of errors.

http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Ffeeds%2Ftag%3Ftagnames%3Drobotframework%26sort%3Dnewest

Has anyone else encountered this?

Comment: There is an invisible control character (*Shift In*, `U+000F`, `^O`) on line 1007 column 152, right before `x&#188;`. The parser is choking on it. That character may be present in the original post, but it should probably be filtered or escaped in the feed.